# How to update the existing csv file with values with comma separated files using python

Tags: python, csv

I have the code to fetch the details from AWS Console,
I have a CSV file with key and values. where the key is already written.
Now I am trying to store the values generated during runtime in CSV next to comma separated key.

my python code:

```
import boto3
instance_count=[]
region = 'USA'
conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, 
aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
instances= conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
for instance in instances:
   instance_count.append(instance)
   instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))
   print('Instance count ->' + str(len(instance_count)))
   ##output: Instance count ->4
```

but i need to store in same csv as below:

My csv be like :

```
    Param_Name,Param_Value
    p_instance_count,
```

Now I want to store the count (Eg: 4) that gets printed in cmd prompt inside csv next to p_instance_count,4

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import boto3
import csv

f = csv.writer(open("instance_count.csv", "a+"), lineterminator="\n")
instance_count=[]
region = 'us-east-1'
conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key,
aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
instances= conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name',
'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
for instance in instances:
    instance_count.append(instance)
    instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))
    print('Instance count ->' + str(len(instance_count)))
    ##output: Instance count ->4
f.writerow(('p_instance_count', len(instance_count)))
```

Comment: You want only one row ?

Comment: Ok I think that this will do the job.

Comment: If you want to overwrite the file than use 'w' instead of 'a+':
 f = csv.writer(open("instance_count.csv", "w"), lineterminator="\n")

Comment: You need to do it with code:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98627/updating-a-csv-file

Comment: How can I write this file in the UTF-8 format so that it can be read as well write?

Comment: ok The csv is getting created in ANSI format which is not getting read. I want the file to be in UTF-8 I tried encoding but getting an error!

Comment: You can ask new question about this and I'll be glad to answer it.

Comment: i have asked a question about this can you help me ? How can I convert the ANSI format csv to UTF-8 using python?